# Microsoft Graph API Groups Delta Query Never Returns Delta Query (Infiinite loop with nextLink)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

While working with Microsoft Graph Explorer, I noticed that when you submit a groups delta request like https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/delta, you will get a response with the @odata.nextLink available. However, when I follow the provided link, I start getting exactly the same set of groups as in the previous response with another @odata.nextLink leading to the endless recursion if I keep following the links. The expected behavior is to get @odata.deltaLink at some point but in never arrives in the responses received. I have 63 groups in my Azure environment.

Tried excluding members from the query but sending https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta?$select=displayName. In this case, I get @odata.deltaLink on the second page after following @odada.nextLink once.

Comment: Could you formulate your question in such a way that you're actually asking the community a specific question?

Comment: I posted the above issue following Microsoft's suggestion: "If you have a question, need help, or are experiencing an issue with your code, we encourage you to post your question or issue on **Stack Overflow**. Tag your question with [microsoftgraph]or [Office 365]." In this case, I'm posting an issue, not a question. The only question I have is how to get it return @deltaLink to finish the recursion? Thanks.

Comment: Microsoft does not state to post issues with their code here, but issues with your own code. The format on StackOverflow is to ask a specific question, with details about what you've tried so far.

Comment: I will post it on Microsoft's GitHub page then. Thank you for you help.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea! You're welcome and thanks for contributing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok , i figured it out how to solve the issue.   When Delta changes returns groups that has more than 1000 members , then is returning the same data set but adding the rest of members. It seems that is an inifinite loop but really is bringing the rest of members.  Then if you do a query with select without expanding members, then you avoids the infinite loop.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-groups#paging-through-members-in-a-large-group

Comment: For me that was not the issue, as far as I understand it, I have an infinite loop, or just a lot of empty responses until I'll get the delta link. I had 150 empty responses before my function timedout. I issued another question here https://stackoverflow.com/q/62150331/1020530

Comment: Any idea how to retrieve users delta information.. consider the use-case where I need to retrieve a specific user group delta or event delta.. basically in incremental mode how do we retrieve a user's all apps delta data?

Answer (score 0):

Stack is the correct place to ask questions like this. Our github issues are to raise content issues, not asking how to use the API itself.

There is a specific doc that shows you how to get changes on the groups api here in our documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-groups

When you call you'll get the first results back.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta?$select=displayName,description&$expand=members
```

Then rather than making this exact same call next time, you would call the @odata.nextLink that was returned in the response to request above which includes a skip token.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta?$skiptoken=pqwSUjGYvb3jQpbwVAwEL7yuI3dU1LecfkkfLPtnIjvB7XnF_yllFsCrZJ
```

a third call, you would call the @odata.nextLink from the second response. The @odata.nextLink should be different bewtween these requests.