# Microsoft Graph API groups delta never returns deltaLink, which is causing infinite loop (with nextLink)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-delta

I'm working with the Microsoft Graph API
I'm using the Delta API for groups. I create one delta request per group (I'm not tracking all groups, only specific ones).

I have checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55379873/microsoft-graph-api-groups-delta-query-never-returns-delta-query-infiinite-loop) and read the documentation mentioned. And I have read the issue on GitHub [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/4263)

I'm working against the same tenant while developing for few weeks with the delta response. Besides once, it always worked almost as expected. When I made a delta request I got the nextLink, I followed it until I got the deltaLink.
I'm saying it almost work as expected, because a lot of times, after the first/two responses with data, I got most of the time another 1-3 next links with no additional data.

The last time I have tried, I got around 150 responses with nextLinks until the function timeout, all of those response besides the first few, had no data in it.

This is a testing environment with around 30 users on the group.

I have used

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta?$select=id,displayName,members&$filter=id eq 'groupId'`
```

In the infinite loop those are the kind of responses I get

```
{
   "id":"402-xxx-ee0",
   "status":200,
   "headers":{
      "Preference-Applied":"odata.track-changes",
      "Cache-Control":"no-cache",
      "OData-Version":"4.0",
      "Content-Type":"application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false;charset=utf-8"
   },
   "body":{
      "@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#groups",
      "@odata.nextLink":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta?$skiptoken=5ZZ_<long_token>_OXWrtiE",
      "value":[

      ]
   }
}
```

As you can see their is no data in the value, but still I get nextLink
When I'm following this next link I'm getting

```
{
   "id":"402-xxx-ee0",
   "status":200,
   "headers":{
      "Preference-Applied":"odata.track-changes",
      "Cache-Control":"no-cache",
      "OData-Version":"4.0",
      "Content-Type":"application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false;charset=utf-8"
   },
   "body":{
      "@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#groups",
      "@odata.nextLink":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta?$skiptoken=5ZZ_<long_token>_DNF5rRE0",
      "value":[

      ]
   }
}
```

As you can see, another response, with another next link (a different one) which again return empty value.

This happens again an again until my function timed out.

I'm expecting to get the deltaLink before at the first response with no more data, or at the maximum at the first empty response.

Comment: I tried to reproduce this issue but failed to repro. Can you provide the process to follow and repro the issue

Comment: @SruthiJ-MSFTIdentity. Do you never get even one empty results with a next link? Since this is happen almost all the time. Regarding it happening in a very long/infinite loop, it happens to me only twice. It is as simple as making delta request to one specific group with query for displayName,id,members. Currently it happened on the first delta call (I mean the first time I'm doing the delta request and following the next links until I get a delta link (I didn't do too many second delta requests yet). What other data are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Responses with an empty array as the value and a nextlink are a normal behavior of the delta function for identity entities (users, groups, applications, service principals...) indicating that not all changes have been enumerated and replication of changes is happening in the backend.

Whenever you are presented with this situation (empty array + next link), your application should pause before querying the nextlink, giving time for replication to happen and avoiding an infinite loop.

If you see this behavior happening too often under normal conditions you should contact support.

Comment: Thank you I will. I do see it almost every time with at least one or 2 empty arrays, on testing account with no changes or any use of any of the users or the admin. I'll contact support

Comment: don't forget to mark as answer if this answers your question :)